# Visual Studio 2013 Javascript Intellisense syncs file in obj folder. Is it possible to exclude folders from syncing?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, javascript-intellisense

I've set up the _references.js file to contains references to javascript I need. I turned on the `autosync` option and everything is fine. Intellisense works as expected.

The problem is that when I publish my project (I precompile and merge all output to a single assembly) the `obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Scripts` folder is filled with javascript files I have in my project (and that I already referenced in _references.js) and the _references.js gets automatically synced and those files are added to it which is very bad.

Is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only happens when you have "Show All Files" enabled in the Solution Explorer. Turn it off and all of the references to "../obj/*" will be removed. Whether this is a bug or by design, I do not know, but I've started [this issue on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/869698/references-js-adds-references-to-obj-js-when-show-all-files-is-enabled-in-solution-explorer) to find out.

Comment: you are definitely right, if it's not a bug sounds like a shitty features.